Linked in API job post on behalf of the organization with scope w_organization_social, w_member_social ,r_organization_social
I’m working on integrating LinkedIn’s API in my React application to post jobs on behalf of our organization. I’ve obtained an access token with the following permissions:
w_organization_social

w_member_social

r_organization_social

r_member_social

Below are the request headers and body I’m using for the job posting request.
const config = {   headers: {     Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,     "Content-Type": "application/json",     "LinkedIn-Version": "202401",     "x-restli-protocol-version": "2.0.0",   }, };

const requestBody = {   author: `urn:li:person:${PERSON_ID}`,   commentary: "Your job posting description here",   visibility: "PUBLIC",   distribution: {     feedDistribution: "MAIN_FEED",     targetEntities: [],     thirdPartyDistributionChannels: [],   },   lifecycleState: "PUBLISHED",   elements: [     {       integrationContext: `urn:li:organization:${ORG_ID}`,       companyApplyUrl: "https://cubiclogics.com",       externalJobPostingId: "12345",       jobPostingOperationType: "CREATE",       title: "Software Developer in Test",       description: "Your detailed job description here",       listedAt: Date.now(),       location: "Sunnyvale, California",       categories: ["rsch"],       industries: ["urn:li:industry:55"],       skillsDescription: "Required skills: JavaScript, Python, HTML/CSS",       companyJobCode: "company_12345",       employmentStatus: "FULL_TIME",       experienceLevel: "EXECUTIVE",       trackingPixelUrl: "http://www.trackingpixellocation.com/pixel.gif",       listingType: "BASIC",     },   ], };

//This is my code
async function postJobToLinkedIn() {
  try {
    let res = await axios.post(
      "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts",
      requestBody,
      config
    );
    console.log(res, "res from api");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "Error posting job:",
      error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
    );
  }
}

//Response
{
    "message": "ERROR :: /elements :: unrecognized field found but not allowed",
    "status": 422
}

I’m receiving a 422 status error with the message indicating that the /elements field is unrecognized.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified the fields in the request body to ensure they align with
LinkedIn’s documentation.
Ensured that permissions are set correctly.
Checked for LinkedIn’s latest API updates, especially for fields
related to job posts.


Indeed, the elements field is not supported in the LinkedIn API for job postings.
Furthermore, job postings should be made through the /simpleJobPostings endpoint, not /posts.
For more details, refer to the LinkedIn Job Postings API Documentation.
